# jQuery Form Processing troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem to process the data from my html form with jQuery. I have this simple form:

```
<form id="singup">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="signup-name">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="signup-email">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="signup-pass">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" id="signup-retype-pass">
  <button class="button-hover" type="submit" id="signup-submit">Create account now</button>
</form>
```

Now I want to get the value of the inputs with jQuery.

```
$("#singup").submit(function (e) {
    var email = $('#singup-email').val();
    console.log(email);
    e.preventDefault(e);
});
```

But the browser console tells me the var `email` is undefined. Why?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You misspelled `$('#singup-email').val();`. It should be `$('#signup-email').val();`

Comment: lol. This is a very big facepalm moment...... Thank you bro!

Comment: Did you even try to debug your code lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo mistake. use `signup-email` not `singup-email`

```
$("#singup").submit(function (e) {
    var email = $('#signup-email').val();
    console.log(email);
    e.preventDefault(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#signup-submit").on('click', function (e) {
    var email = $('#signup-email').val();
    console.log(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="singup">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="signup-name">
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="signup-email">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="signup-pass">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" id="signup-retype-pass">
  <button class="button-hover" type="button" id="signup-submit">Create account now</button>
</form>
```